# Print all pandigital numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Given a base as input, output all pan-digital numbers. A number is pan-digital if it includes every digit in that base at least once, possibly multiple times. Every number is considered to contain an infinite number of leading 0s.

[sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules apply. Given a base, you may either:

- Given an index, output the n-th pan-digital number in that base
- Output all pan-digital numbers up to a given index, or
- Output all pan-digital numbers in that base in ascending order.

You may also submit a function that outputs a generator or infinite list.

### Test cases

```
2 -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... (all natural numbers)
3 -> 5, 7, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19...
4 -> 27, 30, 39, 45...
...
10 -> 123456789, 123456798...
```

Comment: The sequence rules apply is a little confusing.  You say they apply but then you skip options included for sequence in the default, such as outputing a generator or infinite list.  Does the output need to be *printed*?

Comment: "Output all pandigital numbers in that base infinitely" has a degenerate solution.  Start with the last one.  It begins with an infinite number of 1's.  It cannot be shown to be a noncompliant implementation.

Comment: @Wyck they have to be in order

Comment: @Wyck Regardless of the clarification mousetail offered, that's nonsense… If a program outputs nothing, it isn't a solution. There is also no natural number that "begins with an infinite number of 1s": natural numbers are finite. And in "it cannot be shown" you may be confusing the halting problem with the analysis of _individual_ non-terminating programs, which is perfectly possible.

Comment: @Lynn For any n, there is a pandigital number that begins what that many ones. My point was that if you chose one such number and started displaying it there's no way **for a test** to distinguish between being stuck in a loop and printing a compliant number that is larger than you expected.  That's not a program that _outputs nothing_.  I'm saying a golf program that outputs 1s cannot be demonstrated to be noncompliant **via testing**, only by static analysis. So it's better to just explicitly say "display all of them in ascending order" and then I'd have nothing to complain about.

Comment: @Wyck on this site we assume no numerical limits, so you must prove your solution to be valid even if it wouldn't be distinguishable in practice

Comment: I'm having a hard time with your opposition to changing the text from "_Output all pan-digital numbers in that base infinitely_" to "_Output all pan-digital numbers in that base in ascending order_"  The latter is more concise -- that's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 9):

## x86-64 machine code, 28 bytes

```
31 C0 FF C0 50 31 C9 99 F7 FE 0F AB D1 01 C2 75 F6 58 FF C1 0F A3 F1 19 D7 73 E7 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLBTsMwDIbPyVOYoUkJ7dBAaEgr4w24cEJiHNokXV116Wg66GB7dYrTFRhw4EIOsVP7//K7ihotlGrb2C1BwO1A8HTKmrICEzeh33hZTBla1eVstXYZVD7repTvUQ1H6lH6kTPU@ATGIWdJ7fq6pu5Ya5/siSy3L4AF0crVHtbxiUOqXuQRLklIhD0ip56y4GbKKlNzOZARR1tDKvxuQ/AhkRE8lUh3CRm1x4Qt1trAlas1lqfZdadYxmiF5K90f0XnVAxg62kspZE6Wg4zGEcUjmZwNqEkCCSHg/UpHF7gIITcqz@@ze0oGP3z@m4Pyd55RIHsXVL07hiNc2BhiFvyhV72x1jsS9ZPk4o8ROmlu8Op5vYmVhlaA6rUZtpZ8tTGU0PY0FGX8PoFG5/fEW0zE2JtHS6s0aCyuDqRqbxvHmS0g@cMCwO/6xBAEwTe5s@SOfzTIIYIyaY2Ts4tXdX4Ij2OdWVpTr5r31RaxAvXjpaTC9rojc9IaYp3)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes a 0-index in EDI and the base in ESI, and returns a number in EAX.

In assembly:

```
f:  xor eax, eax    # Set EAX to 0. EAX will hold the number being tested.
ol: inc eax         # Increase EAX by 1.
    push rax        # Save the value of RAX (containing EAX) onto the stack.
    xor ecx, ecx    # Set ECX to 0.
il: cdq             # Set EDX to 0 by sign-extending EAX.
    idiv esi        # Divide EDX:EAX by ESI (the specified base).
                    # The quotient goes in EAX and the remainder goes in EDX.
    bts ecx, edx    # Set the bit in ECX at position EDX (a digit) to 1.
    add edx, eax    # Add EAX to EDX.
    jnz il          # Jump back if the result of the addition is nonzero.
            # This loop will exit when the quotient and remainder are both zero.
            # This performs one more iteration after EAX first becomes zero,
            # thereby processing one leading zero and ending with EAX=0, EDX=0.
    pop rax         # Restore the value of RAX (containing EAX) from the stack.
    inc ecx         # Add 1 to ECX.
    bt ecx, esi     # Set CF to the bit in ECX at position ESI (the base).
            # If all digits are present, ECX was (2^base)-1 and became 2^base,
            # and then CF=1. Otherwise, ECX is lower, and CF=0.
    sbb edi, edx    # Subtract EDX+CF from EDI (thus -1 when EAX is pandigital).
    jnc ol          # Jump back, to repeat, except when it goes from 0 to -1.
    ret             # Return.
```

Comment: `bts` sets a bit to 1, not 0.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>74</s> 71 bytes

*-3 thanks to pan*

```python
def f(b,i=1):b-len({i//b**k%b for k in range(i+1)})or print(i);f(b,i+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU31zNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLSlKTS4tKs7Mz8vJzM0s0TA00NKy1FxaWpKma3HTPSU1TSFNI0kn09ZQ0ypJNyc1T6M6U18_SUsrWzVJIS2_SCFbITNPoSgxLz1VI1PbULNWEyhWUJSZV6KRqWkN1goUhRi3GiKepmGsCRVZsABCAwA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Thanks, hope I'm doing everything right :)

Comment: You can use a set comprehension for [71 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU31zNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLSlKTS4tKs7Mz8vJzM0s0TA00NKy1FxaWpKma3HTPSU1TSFNI0kn09ZQ0ypJNyc1T6M6U18_SUsrWzVJIS2_SCFbITNPoSgxLz1VI1PbULNWEyhWUJSZV6KRqWkN1goUhRi3GiKepmGsCRVZsABCAwA).

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒ*IвÙgQ
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@TheThonnu* (`¾šêIL<Q` to `0šÙgQ`).
-1 byte thanks to *@alephalpha* (`Iв0š` to `*Iв`).

Given \$n\$, outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5O0PC9sOjwzPfD/f2MA)

**Explanation:**

```python
∞         # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ        # Filter it by:
  *       #  Multiply the current integer to the (implicit) input-integer
   Iв     #  Convert it to base-input as list
     Ù    #  Uniquify this list
      g   #  Pop and push its length
       Q  #  Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input-integer
          # (after which the filtered infinite list is output implicitly)
```

Multiplying the integer by the input results in an additional trailing `0` in the base-converted list (thanks *@alephalpha*).

Comment: [10](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsqSSdCywr7FocOqZ0lR//8z)

Comment: @TheThonnu Ah, of course. Thanks! And another byte can be saved by removing the second `I` for implicit input. :)

Comment: [8](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5O0PC9sOjwzPfD/f2MA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: @alephalpha Oh, smart way to get rid of the prepend \$0\$! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

Longer than [EzioMercer's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257760/58563) but works in theory<sup>1</sup> for any base, rather than up to \$36\$.

Expects `(base)(n)` where both arguments are BigInts. Returns the \$n\$-th term of the sequence, 1-indexed.

```javascript
b=>g=(k,q=x=1n,o=1n)=>q?g(k,q/b,o|1n<<q%b):k&&-~g(k-=-~o>>b,++x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1RC4IwFEb/yh5KNtwWmk/qXdAv0WsqpeymRgilf33NIOjl8J3z8t3KZzlV4/X@UJYutWvAIZgWeCcHmCGykjwEmOHUbu2Akt6RzfNhjyLtgkCtvitQKxmDMgxn4RoaOTJgsc0YshxYso0wFKwiO1Ff655aXpzLqWa7Fy6pZ8NRcH@0yJ/E/3L8l@QrWutCZO4D)

*<sub>1: In practice, it's ironically worse because of the recursion.</sub>*

#### Without recursion, 70 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

Backport of the C port.

```javascript
b=>k=>{for(q=x=o=1n;k;q=q/b||(k-=-~o>>b,x+=o=1n))o|=1n<<q%b;return~-x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNDoIwFISv0oUmbaA1ogtjeV14EigWo5A@W9CQ8HP1CiQmbGbmy2TmlX/zpvDPd8st3k0oIWhQFai@RE8ddIBwtLKSDtxBDwOtOPAJldJxF60dYzjMlqZur6U37cfbiXdjWPaaAEmsJJqkQC5LiCJGCrQN1kbU@KDZLW8M2fV6vM5aUs3ofDnGf0i2cNrCeQUhRMZk@AE)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 66 bytes

*-1 thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*
*-1 thanks to [@c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)*

A port of the JS version, but obviously without the benefit of BigInts.

```c
o,q,x;f(b,k){for(q=x=0;k;q=q/b?:(k-=-~o>>b,x+=o=1))o|=1<<q%b;--x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RCoIwGIXvfYofQdhwszSvnL9Bz9GN0xSxXNMowezRW5PyoovD@eCDwyl4XRTGKKbZKCoiWUunSvVE44hb0QqNeiP3CWk58pfKMslGHxWGlKonhmmqPSk4H8Vs7qop4ZI3HaEwOQDLStPdQAJCJGylCLFt3/96gGtvfUXcQz6cwCsTG/aXIAiOnctAMliuQUh/EK2wWyGmVNjR2ZnNu6jOeT0Y/vgA)

Comment: Suggest `q/b?:` instead of `q?q/b:` since `q%b = 0` is contemplated with `o=1`, also possible is using `!q?...` and getting rid of the parentheses

Comment: Similarly [70](https://tio.run/##TYxNDoIwFISv0oUmbaA1ogtjeV14EigWo5A@W9CQ8HP1CiQmbGbmy2TmlX/zpvDPd8st3k0oIWhQFai@RE8ddIBwtLKSDtxBDwOtOPAJldJxF60dYzjMlqZur6U37cfbiXdjWPaaAEmsJJqkQC5LiCJGCrQN1kbU@KDZLW8M2fV6vM5aUs3ofDnGf0i2cNrCeQUhRMZk@AE)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
⁰τꜝ⁰ɽ⊍¬)ȯ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigbDPhOqcneKBsMm94oqNwqwpyK8iLCIiLCI2XG4zIl0=)

Prints the first n pandigital numbers. Takes n then base.

*-1 thanks to @mathcat*

*-1 thanks to @AndrovT*

### Explained (old)

```
⁰τUs⁰ɽ~↔⁼)ȯ
         )ȯ  # First n numbers where:
⁰τ           #   that number in base input
  Us         #   uniquified sorted
    ⁰ɽ ↔     #   with digits from the range [1, input) kept
      ~ ⁼    #   equals that range
```

Comment: Ninja'd! I was just about to post [this 12 byte answer](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnuKInic/z4QwcHNVP8qB4oG8IiwiIiwiMyJd)

Comment: @TheThonnu and outgolfed too :p

Comment: [noob](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigbDPhFVz6pyd4oGwyb3igbwpyK8iLCIiLCIxMFxuNCJd)

Comment: [9](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigbDPhOqcneKBsMm94oqNwqwpyK8iLCIiLCI2XG4zIl0=)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 59 bytes

```javascript
b=>{for(i=0;++i;)new Set(i.toString(b)+0).size<b||print(i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/ydauOi2/SCPT1sBaWzvTWjMvtVwhOLVEI1OvJD@4pCgzL10jSVPbQFOvOLMq1SappqYAKAaU1qz9n6ZhovkfAA)

### UPD 62 -> 60

Thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257752/print-all-pandigital-numbers/257760?noredirect=1#comment569606_257760) to reduce bytes count

### UPD 60 -> 59

Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld) for the [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/257752/print-all-pandigital-numbers/257760?noredirect=1#comment569607_257760) to reduce bytes count

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 113 bytes

This code works for any base, rather than up to 36 and without a recursion

Expects one argument - `b (base)` as `BigInt`

```javascript
b=>{for(n=0n;a=[],p=0n,k=++n;new Set(a).size<b||console.log(n)){while(k/b**p++);while(p--)k-=(a[p]=k/b**p)*b**p}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBDsIgEAC/4pGFUj14w/UTHpseoIIiZCGlsYlt346aXiYzmZd@6zKMPk@S0t1Wh9XgdXFpZIQnUhq7vsk/awIKQYrsfLjZiWloi//Yi1nXIVFJ0bYxPRgBLPPTR8vC0XCehQC1d5YSgkSmu9zjPoH/uW3VsTNB/QI)

Comment: `+'0'` can be `+0` for -2.

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/ydauOi2/SCPT1sBaWzvTWjMvtVwhOLVEI1OvJD@4pCgzL10jSVPbQFOvOLMq1SappqYAKAaU1qz9n6ZhovkfAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1bŻĠṫʋ#
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the base on the left and the number of pan-digital numbers to find on the right and yields a list.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98w6ejuIwse7lx9qlv5////Jv8NDQA)**

#### How?

```
1bŻĠṫʋ# - Link: integer, B; integer, N
1       - set the left argument to one (k=1)
      # - increment (k), yielding the first (N) for which:
     ʋ  -   last four links as a dyad - f(k, B):   e.g. k=23, B=3
 b      -     convert (k) to base (B)                   [2,1,2]
  Ż     -     prefix with a zero                        [0,2,1,2]
   Ġ    -     group indices by their values -           [[1],[3],[2,4]]
    ṫ   -     tail (that) from index (B) -                      [[2,4]]
        -       (the empty list is falsey, other lists are truthy)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 46 bytes

```
n->for(i=1,oo,#Set(digits(i*n,n))<n||print(i))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN_XydO3S8os0Mm0NdfLzdZSDU0s0UjLTM0uKNTK18nTyNDVt8mpqCooy80o0MjU1IbqWpGmYQJkLFkBoAA)

Saved some bytes by multiplying `n` instead of prepending `0`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
If[DigitCount[n#,#]~FreeQ~0,Echo@n]~Do~{n,∞}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zMt2iUzPbPEOb80ryQ6T1lHObbOrSg1NbDOQMc1OSPfIS@2ziW/rjpP51HHvFq1/wFFmXklCg7p0Sax/wE) (press "play" to stop running)

prints sequence to infinity

-4 bytes from @alephalpha

Comment: `Most@DigitCount[n,#]` -> `DigitCount[n#,#]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
⟨×Bul=⟩#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9H8FYenO5Xm2D6av1L5/39DAy4TAA)

Takes `n`, then `b`; returns the first `n` pandigital numbers in base `b`. Uses the same trick as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257754/67312) to add a zero.

Explanation of older answer below:

```
⟨       ⟩#   # find the first n positive integers with a truthy result of:
 B          # convert to base b (implicitly pushed)
  0+        # add 0 to the list
    u       # uniquify
     l=     # is the length equal to the base (implicitly pushed again)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>29 24 23</s> 20 bytes

```
W1{I#UQy*aTDa=aPyUy}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhZbwg2rPZVDAyu1EkNcEm0TAypDK2shUlAVi6ONY6FMAA)

*-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen and @alephalpha* 
*-3 thanks to @DLosc*

##### Explanation

```python
W1{I#UQy*aTDa=aPyUy}  # Implicit input on command line
                      # y is automatically initialised to 0
                      # (in a numerical context)
W1{                }  # while True:
   I                  #  if
    #                 #   the length of
       y*a            #   y * input
          TDa         #   in base input
     UQ               #   uniquified
             =        #   equals
              a       #   the input
               Py     #  then print y
                 Uy   #  increment y
```

Old:

```python
Y1W1{ISNUQyTDaPE0=,a{Py}Yy+1}  # Implicit input on command line
Y1                             # Set y to 1
  W1{                       }  # while True:
     I                         #  if
          yTDa                 #   y in base input
              PE0              #   with a 0 prepended,
      SNUQ                     #   sorted and uniquified
                 =             #   equals
                  ,a           #   range(0, input)
                    {  }       #  then
                     Py        #   print y
                        Yy+1   #  y = y + 1
```

Comment: `yTDaPE0` can be `y*aTDa` for -1 (a tip I got from [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257755/52210) on my 05AB1E answer).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen nice, thanks!

Comment: A couple small tips: 1) If there's one statement in the body of an if or loop, you can drop the curly braces; 2) `Uy` works for `++y`.

Comment: As to `y`, it's initialized to `""` (see the [global variables list](https://dloscutoff.github.io/pipdoc/vars#global-variables)). In numeric contexts, that gets treated as zero.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>98</s> <s>97</s> <s>96</s> 94 bytes

Given a base \$b\$, it'll output the infinite sequence separated by newlines (pretty similar to [*@EzioMercer*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257760/52210)):

```java
b->{for(int i=0;;)if(b.toString(++i*b,b).chars().distinct().count()==b)System.out.println(i);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY67DsIwDEV3vsJjQmmExBiVnQEWRsSQpA9c2gQlLhJC/fZgoIsfV7o6pzdPU/b1PbvBpARHg/69AkBPTWyNa@D0fQGeAWtw4sB510SwUnM8r3gkMoQOTuChyrbcv9sQBfcBq63WElthFYUzRfSdKApc242Vyt1MTEKqGhOhd8SnC5PnXVVWnl@JmlGFidSDezR4gVLPWX@Bj8kODFy4P7GRtcUfcbka@Vf2yond4jnnDw)

Original answer **(<s>98</s> <s>97</s> 95 bytes)**: Given two inputs \$b\$ and \$n\$, outputs the \$n^{th}\$ term in base-\$b\$.

```java
b->n->{int r=0,i,t;for(;n>0;)n-=b.toString(++r*b,b).chars().distinct().count()<b?0:1;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY8xb4MwEIV3fsWJydRgQacqxnSr1KFTxqqDTSC5lBhkH5GiKL@dGsWVqqpDB/s96d199jvqsy6Ou8@lHbT38KbRXhMAT5qwhWNIxUw4iH62LeFoxUs09aulbt@5/D8zUZsGelCLKRpbNFe0BE6VOeYk@9ExaZtSZrZQRtC4JYd2zzh3DyY3mWgP2nmWiR16wkAPth1nG7Q2z@Wmkq6j2Vlw8rbIJDSYZjOEBrHIecQdnEI5dge/f@hs7Qmwvrz@xKhHCaZWT@HmPIYA24un7iTGmcQUFomlRvuuSLnh6QbSTMa5bwyqSgLWqiqDBE6M/wD1Qk/TcGGh3N1gxtMfxN8Lg2UxuyXruS1f)

**Explanation:**

```java
b->n->{                // Method with two integer parameters and integer return-type
  int r=0;             //  Result-integer, starting at 0
  for(;n>0;)           //  Loop as long as input `n` is not 0 yet:
    n-=                //   Decrease `n` by:
       b.toString(++r  //    Increase the result-integer by 1 first with `++r`
                  *b   //    Multiply the new `r` by base `b`
                       //    (this is to get an additional trailing 0)
                  ,b)  //    Convert `r*b` to base-`b`,
        .chars()       //    Convert it to an IntStream of codepoint integers
        .distinct()    //    Uniquify this IntStream
        .count()       //    Get how many items are left
       <b?             //    If this is smaller than base `b`:
          0            //     Leave `n` the same by decreasing with 0
         :             //    Else (the count is equal to `b` instead):
          1;           //     Decrease `n` by 1
  return r;}           //  After the loop, return the result-integer
```

Minor note: `.distinct().count()` is 4 bytes shorter than Java 16+'s `.boxed().toSet().size()`.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 16 bytes

```
{&x=#'?'+0,x\!y}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxFT9tOwkAUfN+vGKMRiNvL3rq0G/UneEMSammhobTYFi0h+O2eBo0Pkz0zZ+Zspkguj8Pz/eR18hTy4e3ufGVskVwelufvNingY3DrZu+m6yItKze4s2tnqytbLCWsE5BQ0DCIViQpyNAZWAgBoSEMRARBNB63Gjpy0kKFUDG0WTEW4DNvz+iq5ovmxVKEEFJpE83D0N0mO49/NRvPxwjb9f2xS4Igazb5tqkKv+vTbJ8P2S6tt7mfNYfg45R3fdnUXSCNtUYGx7asey+tKu+Y1ptyW/Zp5dWnw3vedoxJeC8QHJJDcWgOwxH5vo8pJVCn/alN6b3ZZ0yNdrJYTkUJFBBERUQYtZiiTI8mSVSFhJjOmlEeQS3H//7q8f9+tP0B7edkeA==)

Takes the base as `x` and `y` as the zero-based index to generate all "pandigital" numbers up to.

- `x\!y` convert `0..y` to base `x`
- `+0,` prepend a `0`, then transpose to ensure all results contain a leading `0`
- `#'?'` count the number of distinct digits in each value
- `&x=` return indices where all digits are present

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 49 bytes

```julia
>(b,n=1)=1:b-1⊆digits(n;base=b)&&@show(n),b>n+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/304jSSfP1lDT1tAqSdfwUVdbSmZ6ZkmxRp51UmJxqm2SppqaQ3FGfrlGnqZOkl2etiFQh4nmfwA)

prints the sequence indefinitely. Uses the beautiful `⊆` (same as the function `issubset`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＷη«→≧⁻¬⁻…¹θ↨ⅈθη»Ｉⅈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw9D8IgFEXn8isYHwkOJp3spE4ONKaT67MhQILQ8lEH429HMA4uN@fcm9xZY5g92lIubslpzI@7DLCygfy7rv7Uxkpakb5IJ/wm4TAZpVOdOoHLMUaj3LcBYVyOnI7@hzChUxL2nK6M0xNGCTdgzVjNdv4m12BcgjPG1DbGhlJ60pfdZj8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `b` and `n` as input and outputs the `n`th pandigital number in base `b`. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `b` and `n` as integers.

```
Ｗη«
```

Repeat until `n` is zero.

```
→
```

Move right one position. This uses the current column index as the next trial pandigital integer.

```
≧⁻¬⁻…¹θ↨ⅈθη
```

If the set difference between the range from `1` to `b` and the base conversion of the trial integer is empty then decrement `n`.

```
»Ｉⅈ
```

Output the final pandigital integer.

26 bytes to output the first `n` pandigital integers:

```
ＮθＮηＷ‹Ｌυη«→Ｆ¬⁻…¹θ↨ⅈθ⊞υⅈ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY27DsIwDEXn5is8OlIYkDrRDSYkWlWdWEMV4kgloXmUAfHtwWx4sHSu7rFn0nEOeqn17J8lD@VxMxFX2Yl/JuYXucUAXkxKvLzNhEUqICnhLZo@bAYPk7OUudvcQwQcQsbe@ZJw0t4a3CtY2TjqZPCK8kc8MJbEpxRwxOpHjNH5jCedMj@QXa2taOtuW74) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Pushes the pandigital numbers to the predefined empty list as they are found and outputs the final list once `n` pandigital numbers have been found.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

0-indexed

```
o1
@eUfXìNÎ}iV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bzEKQGVVZljsTs59aVY&input=Mwo3)

```
o1\n@eUfXìNÎ}iV     :Implicit input of integers U=base & V=index
o1                  :Range [1,U)
  \n                :Reassign to U
    @               :Function taking an integer X as argument
     e              :  Test U for equality with
      Uf            :    U filtered by elements of
        Xì          :      X converted to digit array in base
          N         :        Array of all inputs
           Î        :        First element (i.e., original U)
            }       :End function
             iV     :Get the Vth integer that returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
.f!-tUQjZQE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy9NUbckNDArKtD1/39jLgsA)

Prints the first n pandigital numbers, take input as base then n.

#### Explanation

```
               # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
          E    # E = eval(input())  (second input)
.f        E    # print the first E numbers which satisfy lambda Z
       jZQ     # convert Z to base Q as a list of digits
    tUQ        # [1, 2,..., Q-1]
   -           # remove all digits in our number from the list of all digits
  !            # not (will be true for empty list)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 65 bytes

```c
j,k;f(*i,b,n){for(*i=j=0;n;j=!j?*i+=k=1:j%b==k?n-=++k/b,*i:j/b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BcoIwFEX3@YpbOnYSEqq4JD79FkOkJthHB9GNw7fTQG2nuzfn3XNvXdSXI39MUzStbWQejDOsHk3Xp5sibSzbSC/xkAdNLZVVXDmi9sAFad2unclDFddO2XF6DVxfbv6E3XXwoXs/74UIPIjPY2B574JX4iGAhNCfBgNnwDaBtAXpQNhaOOwI5cZCa6cwx4GvPimNzFZbXyFLnrILXzxOXmnBi1eigJtd/nVTSr79rT3Ff5V@Lkz/52f8GbwNV5llCxvFOH0D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>93</s> <s>90</s> <s>87</s> 82 bytes

*-3 from @The Thonnu 

-3 from @c-- 

-5 from @user85795*

```python
def f(b,i=1,j=1,*s):i and f(b,i//b,j,i%b,0,*s);b>len({*s})or print(j);f(b,j+1,j+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU31zNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLSlKTS4tKs7Mz8vJzM0s0TA00NKy1FxaWpKma3EzKCU1TSFNI0kn09ZQJwuItYo1rTIVEvNSIKL6-kk6WTqZqkk6BiAp6yS7nNQ8jWqt4lrN_CKFgqLMvBKNLE1rkNosbUMQhpq8JE3DGMpcsABCAwA)
Infinitely prints out values.

Comment: [90](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3o1JS0xTSNJJ0Mm0NNa3SbXMSc5NSEhXydLSKrfIUEvNSFNI18vT1k3TyVJOAYpr5RdVaxbXWOal5GukamToGmpq2tklgdQVFmXklGpma1mDTtA01ITashoinaRhrQkVgdgMA)

Comment: Also, you might want to add something like `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(10**9)` in the header since at the moment it only prints values up to 1000.

Comment: building on @TheThonnu, [87](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3w1NS0xTSNJJ0Mm0NNa3SbXMSc5NSEhXydLSKrfIUEvNSFNI18vT1k3TyVJOAYpr5RdVaxbXWSXY5qXka6RqZOgaaQDGFgqLMvBKNTE1rsFHahpoQ41dDxNM0jDWhIjCLAQ)

Comment: [83](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU31zNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLSlKTS4tKs7Mz8vJzM0s0TA00NKy1FxaWpKma3EzOCU1TSFNI0kn09ZQJ8vWQEerWNMqUyExLwUiqq-fpJOlkF-kkKmTqZqkA5a3TrLLSc3TqNYqrtUEyhQUZeaVaGRpWoM0ZGkbQo1ekqZhDGUuWAChAQ) by merging f and g.

Comment: [82](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwU31zNyC_KISheLKYi4g1itOLSlKTS4tKs7Mz8vJzM0s0TA00NKy1FxaWpKma3EzKCU1TSFNI0kn09ZQJwuItYo1rTIVEvNSIKL6-kk6WTqZqkk6BiAp6yS7nNQ8jWqt4lrN_CKFgqLMvBKNLE1rkNosbUMQhpq8JE3DGMpcsABCAwA) with the same idea.